# Python: sqlparse not parsing oracle stored procedure

Tags: python

Am using sqlparse module in python in order to parse sqls. But am facing an issue while parsing the PLSQL procedure, its taking as statement for each delimeter ;

Below is the sample procedure,

```
> create procedure test As Empid varchar2(100); begin select
> max(emp_id)+1 into Empid from employees; Insert into employees(emp_id,
> hire_date) Values(Empid,Sysdate); Commit; end;
```

while i parse, above procedure is split into 5 statements. Is it possible to get the procedure as a single statement? Please advice.